# Joining strings except empty ones in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, variable-assignment

I was wondering what is the best way to join a few strings in javascript except if they are empty.

Say we have

```
let s1 = 'X = 1';
let s2 = '';
let s3 = 'Z = 3';
```

And my end result need to be  "X = 1, Z = 3"

```
let str = [s1,s2,s3].join(',')  // will have extra comma

let str = [s1!??' , ' ,s2!??' , ' ,s3].join(' ')  //is ugly, and will not work

let str = [u1&&',' ,u2&&',',u3].join('')  //close, but no cigar.
```

But I am sure there must be an elegant way to do this join!

And someone here on stackoverflow will point me in the right direction.

Comment: Use `.filter()` to create a new array without empty strings, and then `.join()` that.

Comment: Thanks.```let str = [u1,u2,u3].filter(e => e.length).join(',');``` works 100%.

Comment: `.filter(Boolean)` will also work since an empty string is falsey value. Also, comma is default delimiter for `.join()` if you really wanna code golf it.

Comment: @Clothahump I added an answer. Did you get a chance to look into that. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.filter(Boolean)` (which is the same as .filter(x => x)) removes all `falsy` values (null, undefined, empty strings etc...)

**Working Demo :**

```js
let s1 = 'X = 1';
let s2 = '';
let s3 = 'Z = 3';

let str = [s1,s2,s3].filter(Boolean).join(", ");

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve the same using the code below.
Filter Boolean eliminates all `falsey` values like undefined, empty strings, null etc

```
  let str = [u1,u2,u3].filter(Boolean).join(',');
```

Comment: Some comments describing this would be helpful.